# Using Dozer how to copy the collection inside a java object but skipping the object itself

Tags: java, mapping, javabeans, dozer

I have source class hierarchy as below

```
Class A {
    List<B> bs;
}

Class B {
    List<C> cs;
}

Class C {
   String n;
}
```

The new destination class hierarchy is as below

```
Class A1 {
    List<C1> cs;
}


Class C1 {
    String n;
}
```

As you can see the destination class hierarchy is skipping bs. How to configure this copying of a property in the object to the destination but skipping the object itself in the source

Comment: Can you post your Dozer mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One crude solution is to pre-process the source and copy the List<C> cs to a transient variable in Class A. The source will look like this after the pre-process

```
Class A {
    List<B> bs;

    transient List<C> cs;
}

Class B {
   List<C> cs;
}

Class C {
   String n; 
}
```